# How to scroll table only in css (horizontal/width)

Tags: css, html-table, scroll

I'm probably not the first to ask this, but I cannot find a working solution anywhere.

This is an extremely simplified version of my page

```html
<table style="white-space:nowrap;font-size:30px"><tr><td style="background-color:blue">SIDE NAV SIDE NAV</td><td>
  <table style="overflow-y:auto">
  <thead>
<tr>
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>
  <th>Job Title</th>
  <th>Twitter</th>
  <th>Comment</th>
   
</tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<tr>
  <td data-column="First Name">James</td>
  <td data-column="Last Name">Matman</td>
  <td data-column="Job Title">Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
  <td data-column="Twitter">@james</td>
  <td>Jack and jill wen up the hill</td>
  
</tr>
<tr>
  <td data-column="First Name">Andor</td>
  <td data-column="Last Name">Nagy</td>
  <td data-column="Job Title">Designer</td>
  <td data-column="Twitter">@andornagy</td>
  <td>Jack and jill wen up the hill</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td data-column="First Name">Tamas</td>
  <td data-column="Last Name">Biro</td>
  <td data-column="Job Title">Game Tester</td>
  <td data-column="Twitter">@tamas</td>
   <td>Jack and jill wen up the hill</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td data-column="First Name">Zoli</td>
  <td data-column="Last Name">Mastah</td>
  <td data-column="Job Title">Developer</td>
  <td data-column="Twitter">@zoli</td>
  <td>Jack and jill wen up the hill</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td data-column="First Name">Szabi</td>
  <td data-column="Last Name">Nagy</td>
  <td data-column="Job Title">Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
  <td data-column="Twitter">@szabi</td>
  <td>Jack and jill wen up the hill</td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>   </td></tr></table>
```

Now I want that only the `table` should scroll. The side nav should always be visible.

I also tried a `div` version with `flex`, instead of a `table`, but the same issue exists.

here is the `div` version

```html
<div style="white-space:nowrap;display:flex;font-size:30px"><div style="background-color:blue">SIDE NAV SIDE NAV</div><div>
  <table style="overflow-y:auto">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Job Title</th>
      <th>Twitter</th>
      <th>Comment</th>       
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-column="First Name">James</td>
      <td data-column="Last Name">Matman</td>
      <td data-column="Job Title">Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
      <td data-column="Twitter">@james</td>
      <td>Jack and jill wen up the hill</td>
      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-column="First Name">Andor</td>
      <td data-column="Last Name">Nagy</td>
      <td data-column="Job Title">Designer</td>
      <td data-column="Twitter">@andornagy</td>
      <td>Jack and jill wen up the hill</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-column="First Name">Tamas</td>
      <td data-column="Last Name">Biro</td>
      <td data-column="Job Title">Game Tester</td>
      <td data-column="Twitter">@tamas</td>
       <td>Jack and jill wen up the hill</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-column="First Name">Zoli</td>
      <td data-column="Last Name">Mastah</td>
      <td data-column="Job Title">Developer</td>
      <td data-column="Twitter">@zoli</td>
      <td>Jack and jill wen up the hill</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-column="First Name">Szabi</td>
      <td data-column="Last Name">Nagy</td>
      <td data-column="Job Title">Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
      <td data-column="Twitter">@szabi</td>
      <td>Jack and jill wen up the hill</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>   </div>
```

If I put a hard-coded fixed width to the table then it works okay. But of course I don't want a fixed width. It has to work for any size screen/browser.

How can this be accomplished?

FWIW: here are the 2 versions in codepen

table:  https://codepen.io/yisman/pen/LYLKzbw

div: https://codepen.io/yisman/pen/GREbMON

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the div solution, just wrap the div surrounding the inner table with a `overflow:auto`. That will create the scroll on the table itself.

```html
<div style="white-space:nowrap;display:flex;font-size:30px"><div style="background-color:blue">SIDE NAV SIDE NAV</div><div style="overflow:auto;">
  <table style="overflow-y:auto">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Job Title</th>
      <th>Twitter</th>
      <th>Comment</th>       
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-column="First Name">James</td>
      <td data-column="Last Name">Matman</td>
      <td data-column="Job Title">Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
      <td data-column="Twitter">@james</td>
      <td>Jack and jill wen up the hill</td>
      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-column="First Name">Andor</td>
      <td data-column="Last Name">Nagy</td>
      <td data-column="Job Title">Designer</td>
      <td data-column="Twitter">@andornagy</td>
      <td>Jack and jill wen up the hill</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-column="First Name">Tamas</td>
      <td data-column="Last Name">Biro</td>
      <td data-column="Job Title">Game Tester</td>
      <td data-column="Twitter">@tamas</td>
       <td>Jack and jill wen up the hill</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-column="First Name">Zoli</td>
      <td data-column="Last Name">Mastah</td>
      <td data-column="Job Title">Developer</td>
      <td data-column="Twitter">@zoli</td>
      <td>Jack and jill wen up the hill</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-column="First Name">Szabi</td>
      <td data-column="Last Name">Nagy</td>
      <td data-column="Job Title">Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
      <td data-column="Twitter">@szabi</td>
      <td>Jack and jill wen up the hill</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>   </div>
```

Obviously, the html needs adjusting, with correctly matching div tags.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you mean this, but hope it could help you.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.sidebar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="white-space:nowrap;display:flex;font-size:30px"><div class="sidebar" style="background-color:blue">SIDE NAV SIDE NAV</div><div>
  <table style="overflow-y:auto">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Job Title</th>
      <th>Twitter</th>
      <th>Comment</th>       
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-column="First Name">James</td>
      <td data-column="Last Name">Matman</td>
      <td data-column="Job Title">Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
      <td data-column="Twitter">@james</td>
      <td>Jack and jill wen up the hill</td>
      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-column="First Name">Andor</td>
      <td data-column="Last Name">Nagy</td>
      <td data-column="Job Title">Designer</td>
      <td data-column="Twitter">@andornagy</td>
      <td>Jack and jill wen up the hill</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-column="First Name">Tamas</td>
      <td data-column="Last Name">Biro</td>
      <td data-column="Job Title">Game Tester</td>
      <td data-column="Twitter">@tamas</td>
       <td>Jack and jill wen up the hill</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-column="First Name">Zoli</td>
      <td data-column="Last Name">Mastah</td>
      <td data-column="Job Title">Developer</td>
      <td data-column="Twitter">@zoli</td>
      <td>Jack and jill wen up the hill</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-column="First Name">Szabi</td>
      <td data-column="Last Name">Nagy</td>
      <td data-column="Job Title">Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
      <td data-column="Twitter">@szabi</td>
      <td>Jack and jill wen up the hill</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>   </div>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your time and your input. I appreciate your effort. but it still feels a bit hacky. since the scroll is on the bottom of the page. not the table. (the table may be shorter then the full page) and its not so intuitive to the user. any better idea?